# How do I mock away Ignition.start()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

For various reasons my unit testing environment won't have access to the environment that's needed to start ignite.  I don't need ignite to start for the test and I'd like for the code to just ignore the call to Ignition.start().  How do I do that?

I've tried mocking away ignition but when I try to mock away the start() method it throws an error.

```
when(ignitionMock.start())
```

This results in the following error:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: You shouldn't need to stub `start()` at all.  By default, all methods on a mock do nothing (and just return a reasonable value, like null or 0, if it's appropriate to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `doNothing()`:

```
doNothing().when(ignitionMock).start();
```

Comment: But if `ignitionMock` is actually a mock, this won't have any effect.